# Xcode 9 The launch image set did not have any applicable content, tvOS/iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

I have a project in Xcode 9 with both a tvOS and iOS build target.  For launching, I want to use the Launch Storyboard for iOS, but I have to have an actual Launch Image for tvOS because it doesn't support Launch Storyboards.

The iOS target became (by some twist of fate) configured to have BOTH a Launch Storyboard AND a Launch Image: ...the tvOS one.

No matter how many times I deselect the Launch Image in the iOS project, Xcode resets it.  Compiling fails with the message "The launch image set named xyz did not have any applicable content"--obviously because the tvOS Launch Image in the asset catalog has nothing for iOS.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened the `project.pbxproj` in a text editor and found the offending entry:

```
19B2900B7DB9219B2900B7DB92 /* Debug */ = {
    isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
    buildSettings = {
        ...
        ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = my_tvos_launch_image;
        ...
    };
    name = Debug;
};
```

Deleting the `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME` entry from the iOS build configs made it forget about the Launch Image.